# callback is not a function :(

Tags: node.js, callback

I wrote the following code, but it breaks down once one of the two events get called, because callback is not a function

```
data.getDB = function (callback) {

    //Connect to the db
    mongoose.connect(config["mongodb-url"]);
    var con = mongoose.connection;

    //Gets called when there is an error connecting to the db
    con.on('error', function () {
        callback(true, false);
    });

    //Gets called when the connection to the db succeeds
    con.on('open', function () {
        callback(false, con);
    });
};
```

edit: here is the call (directly below the first function)

```
data.getDB(function (err, data) {
    if (!err && data) {
        db = data;
        console.log('Sucessfully connected to database');
    } else {
        console.log('Error connecting to database');
    }
});
```

Comment: where do you call data.getdb and do you give it a function as parameter. my guess is you don't define callback when you call your function

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i edited the question sorry

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid and already called it without providing any function from another file